# Logging in using the API

Tags: api, ce-1.5.1.0

I've been poking around the web looking for a solution to this, but I can't seem to find anything concrete. I have a site that has a non-Magento frontend. We're using the cart,  checkout, and users from Magento only. We also have the Magento portion on a subdomain (i.e., store.domain.com), whereas the rest of the site has the standard 'www'.

Right now we're using the method where we include Mage.php and call Mage directly. We'd rather use the API across the board, though.

I have added my own methods for logging in, and they work, but subsequent calls to the api show that the user is no longer logged in:

```
public function __construct()
{
  // Change to the default store so we
  // can grab the frontend user session
  Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('default');

  // Get the customer session
  $this->_session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
}

public function login($email, $password)
{
  try {
    $passed = $this->_session->login($email, $password);
    if ($passed) {
      return $this->_session->getCustomerId();
    }
    return false;
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::logException($e);
  }
}

public function isLoggedIn()
{
  return $this->_session->isLoggedIn();
}
```

Has anyone successfully implemented logging in via the API?

Comment: You might have to return the session ID and use that every time you make a call. Never used the API, just my thought.

Comment: Make sure that magento is writing cookies for JUST the domain itself and not the subdomain, it may be preventing the API from being read on `wwww` if the cookie subdomain is `store.domain.com`.

Comment: Hey Ms. Folco, did you find a solution?

Comment: we ended up going in an entirely different direction (by which i mean they decided to farm it out to offshore devs who will be creating their own home-grown PHP magento api).

Comment: Can you close the question? Either by adding your solution as an answer and accepting it or deleting the post

Comment: actually, i never found a solution. the fact that i am on 1.5.1.0 was edited out of the original post, so the solution below doesn't really answer my particular question :\

Comment: hi @Laura , this is not a right place to comment , but i am in trouble. as Marius suggested here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69170/coupon-code-error-message-for-guest-customers/69171#69171

i am using your magento hackathon extension , but sometimes

after customer applied coupon code and clicked "apply coupon " button,

i am getting these kind of errors : http://prntscr.com/7cjjdq 

can you please give me some solution.

Comment: you can open an issue here: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Hackathon_PromoCodeMessages/issues. please include the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7354/is-there-customer-session-support-via-magentos-rest-api/) where OP is looking for a solution to get a users order data on a 3th party platform they've developed.

There are a couple of answers outlining oAuth as the way to do this. The frontend user will login to the underlying Magento environment granting the platform access to their data.