# Is there customer session support via Magento's REST api?

Tags: magento-1.7, customer, session

I'm working on extending wishlist functionality to Magento's REST api.  It would be nice to access the customer's session.  Does Magento have any support for accessing the customer's session via REST?

Comment: Why do you need session access? The wishlist items are store in the db and have a reference to the customer id. ..Or maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Because I don't have the customer id.

Comment: Ok...seams fair...sorry for my ignorance :)

Comment: No worries!  My question was brief, so a little explanation is probably in order.

Comment: As I read in the Magento REST API Documentation there is no access to the session via REST. Did you think about using oAuth?

Comment: Could you expand on that in an answer? I'll be using oAuth to connect to the REST services, but I still don't see how to get a customer from that.

Comment: Perhaps a valid questions would be what information do you have on the customer? An email address?

Comment: @Toast, The Magento REST API uses oAuth for authorization. I was thinking of a solution where the user logs in via oAuth. It should be possible to obtain further customer details after this which you can use?

Comment: @AnnaVölkl, do you know if this solution exists in Magento?  Or are you thinking of custom code to handle the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments above, I would recommend to provide a user login with oAuth to gain access to the customerID.
To anwer your question: No, it's not possible to access the customer session.

The flow can be as follows:

1. User accesses a 3rd party website where you want to provide the wishlist functionality
2. User request wishlist/wishlist functionality (by adding a new item to wishlist, showing his wishlist etc.)
3. User logs in via oAuth in your magento shop
4. Retrieve customer ID from oAuth
5. Proceed with your wishlist functionality

For the user Authorization, I recommend you follow the sections "Getting an Unauthorized Request Token" and "User Authorization" on this [page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html).

Comment: Your answer was the first to offer a workable solution!

Comment: What is the accepted way of getting customer ID from oAuth? I don't see such functionality anywhere in their docs.

Comment: I have figured it out.  For anyone else having the same issue, ensure that your "customer" role has permissions to access the api

Comment: Hello @Anna Völkl , How i get customer id in magento REST api ? Because when i pass customer token in Header i need customer id which customer token is belonged to that specific customer token in magento 2

Comment: My products API returns products, if i try with customer i am getting error, my url : http://192.168.1.65/anusthana/api/rest/customers error : https://snag.gy/0jbhTr.jpg  can u help me  @Anna

Answer (score 7):

No.

The customer session is tied against the frontend cookie the browsing customer has. If you are using file based sessions these would be stored under var/sessions/ - if you are using the database as session storage this would be stored in core_session.

In any case to be able to access it you would need to know the session_id from the customer which by design should only be between browser and server. *1)

A better approach, as suggested in the comments above, would be to figure out what information you do have available for the customer (customer_id, email address) and then access the wishlist via that.

One further thing to keep in mind is that the session you have established to communicate to the API is separate to the session a customer has.

Overall I feel you would get a more actionable answer if you posted what it is you are trying to achieve with the wishlist stating your current constraints.

*1) you might be able to read the currently used cookie session and save it to the database for further processing, but you will again need some other information to tie this back to the logic you are currently trying to implement, so I do not see any use for it here.

Comment: thanks for the great answer.  My end-goal is to access customer data via REST that the customer sees when logging into the front-end: order history, saved addresses, etc.

Comment: Some more context would certainly help. What application is making these requests? My guess here is that you have a non-Magento website in which you want to display Magento data but this is not quite clear from your question and could be something else completely. The OAuth suggestions involve actions the customer would need to do. Other approaches include sharing the session between the two systems (for example take a look at the various wordpress integrations).

Comment: Your guess is pretty close!  I'm helping to extend basic REST services for an iphone app.  The front-end oauth solves the problem I'm having; sorry for not asking a clearer question.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a mix of the REST API and Magento's OAuth.
With OAuth the frontend user can login onto the Magento environment giving your (3th party) application and access to his customer data like order history.

As far as I know this is as close as you can get to the customer session using the API.

Check out [this Magento documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_configuration.html) on the subject and also this nice article by [Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento-rest-and-oauth-intro/)