# coupon code error message for guest customers

Tags: customer, coupon, coupon-codes

we created a coupon code for registered customers.

when guest try to apply coupon code, than it displaying message like "coupon code is not valid".

but i want to display message "coupon code will apply only for registered customers.

how to write different error message for different coupon codes.

let me know if you need any clarifications

please help me to find solution

thanks in advance

Comment: do you use any coupon module?

Comment: no, default magento  promotions > shopping cart price rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone built such an extension for a hackathon. Not sure if it's finished yet, but you can give it a try. By the description "Provide improved error messages when entering a promo code fails.", it seams that it does what you need: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Hackathon_PromoCodeMessages

Comment: hi @Marius, i am using the extension that you reffered, the problem is ,

when we entered the coupon code and apply the coupon , it will display message as like in the image =  > http://prntscr.com/7brbrz

please help me to find some solution